# Change transform-origin on already scaled element

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to achieve a zoom effect which takes into consideration where on the to-be-zoomed element the user decides to scroll-in i.e. zoom.

In order to achieve this I'm trying to change the transform-origin.

This change seems to cause the element to jump back to it's original position before changing the transform-origin and then scale up the element from that point.

```
if (i === 0) {
    $(this).css({
        'transform': 'scale(2)',
        'transform-origin': '100% 100%'
    });
    i++;
} else {
    $(this).css({
        'transform': 'scale(2.5)',
        'transform-origin': '30% 70%'
    });
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kkw3otm0/5/) that shows what I'm trying to explain.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set in your css: `-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 500ms linear;`
This is valid only for transform, but not for transform-origin, because that's a separate property. That's why the origin jumps on second click. Instead write:

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 500 ms linear, //note the comma-separation
                    -webkit-transform-origin 500ms linear;
```

Now the transform-origin is transitioned too.
In a comma-separated list of properties you can define speed and easing for each property separately.
If you want the same behaviour for all properties, you can simply write:

```
-webkit-transition: all 500ms linear;
```

I have updated your fiddle.